# Привязка значений словаря к свойствам элемента управления

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте!
Как на форме WPF привязаться к свойствам Visibility, Enabled кнопки и других элементов управления через словарь? Элементов управления много. Для идентификации собирался использовать свойство Tag. Tag привязать к ключу словаря, а значения свойств брать из значений словаря (класс, хранящий значения свойств).

Спасибо

**UPD**

Пример разметки:

```
<Grid>
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
  <RowDefinition />
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
 <Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <ColumnDefinition />
   <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
   <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
   <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Кнопка 1" Visibility="???" IsEnabled="???" Tag="1" />
  <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="Кнопка 2" Visibility="???" IsEnabled="???" Tag="2" />
  <Button Grid.Column="3" Content="Кнопка 3" Visibility="???" IsEnabled="???" Tag="3" /> 
 </Grid>    
<!--... тут ContentControl, отображающий по требованию UserControls -->
</Grid>
```

Класс, хранящий значения для свойств, я описал, описал класс, который содержит словарь и работает с ним. Осталось прикрутить их к разметке. На импортной части этого ресурса много об этом пишут, но там в разрезе либо списка (ListBox, ListView, ComboBox), либо текскового свойства элементов TextBox или TextBlock. И идентификации нет.

Comment: паттерн MVVM используете? пример кода разметки тоже не помешал бы

Comment: Да, паттерн MVVM используется.

Comment: Т.е. у вас есть один словарь, в котором хранятся вперемешку всевозможные значения и вы хотите привязаться к значению, которое лежит по определенному ключу?

Comment: По ключу лежат значения для одного элемента полностью. И доступность и видимость, возможно и другие значения других свойств. Сейчас главное понять как выбрать эти два значения по одному ключу. Остальное будет проще

Comment: Дело в том, что для каждого UserControl`а имеется своя комбинация разрешенных и видимых кнопок/элементов меню/и других Control`ов

Answer (score 0):

варианты:

**1.А)** можно использовать свойство string Uid -- вроде бы оно для этого и задумано; **1.Б)** написать наследующийся от требуемого базового типа (например от Button'а) класс с единственным дополнительным свойством-идентификатором (например int ID); пример с Uid:
WPF:

```
<Window x:Class="Test001WpfApp.MainWindow"
        Name="mainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test001WpfApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Name="mainGrid">
        <TextBlock x:Name="someTextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" Margin="0,0,0,27" Uid="1"/>
        <Button x:Name="someButton" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="442,298,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Uid="2"/>
        <CheckBox x:Name="someCheckBox" Content="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,301,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Uid="3"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C# в конструкторе формы:

```
Dictionary<string, object> propertyDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();//"словарь свойств"
            propertyDict.Add(@"1", "Hellow!");//заполняем требуемыми свойствами
            propertyDict.Add(@"2", 123);
            propertyDict.Add(@"3", true);            

            foreach (UIElement formElement in this.mainGrid.Children)
            {
                //придётся следить за типом элемента, если свойства разнородные (при этом не получиться использовать switch-case -- он работает с простыми типами)
                if (formElement is TextBlock)
                {
                    ((TextBlock)formElement).Text = ((string)propertyDict[formElement.Uid]);
                }
                else if (formElement is Button)
                {
                    ((Button)formElement).MaxWidth = ((int)propertyDict[formElement.Uid]);
                }
                else if (formElement is CheckBox)
                {
                    ((CheckBox)formElement).IsChecked = ((bool)propertyDict[formElement.Uid]);
                };
            };
```

Но всё ещё не понятно, как быть если нужно для одного элемента (по уникальному Uid) хранить несколько свойств. Зачем ограничиваться именно словарём, использовать бы произвольную коллекцию (все элементы окна) с доступом по уникальному идентификатору (ключ == имя элемента):
**2)**без словаря Dictionary<,> -- прямо по имени элемента, т.е. например

```
this.mainWindow.GetElementByName(string elementName)
```

возвращаемый тип базовый UIelement => результат привести к ожидаемому типу, чтобы обращаться к свойствам, например вроде

```
((TextBox)GetElementByName(@"usernameTextBox")).Text = @"admin";
```

3)свойство Tag типа object и твой элемент сам по себе тоже ;) и словарь Dictionary<,> как множество пар (*ключ,значение*) есть множество пар (*объект,объект*) -- *значением* может быть непосредственно твой элемент, а ключ на выбор что удобно.

Comment: Это ответ на какой вопрос? Покажите как привязаться к значению, лежащему в Dictionary, имея ключ в Tag элемента.

Comment: @Андрей, если говорим о пункте (3) -- то я как раз НЕ предлагаю "привязаться к значению, лежащему в Dictionary, имея ключ в Tag элемента" =)

Comment: По п.1 - Можно и Uid, только как? Как привязать этот UId и ключ словаря? А потом как привязать значения из этого словаря и свойство, например, Visibility?

Comment: @АртемийСоболев, расписал подробнее п.(1А,Б)

Answer (score 0):

ViewModel

```
    class MainWindowVieModel
{
    public Dictionary<string, bool> EnabledDictionary
    {
        get
        {
            return new Dictionary<string, bool>
            {
                {"button1", true },
                {"button2", true },
                {"button3", false }
            };
        }
    }

    public Dictionary<string, Visibility> VisibilityDictionary
    {
        get
        {
            return new Dictionary<string, Visibility>
            {
                {"button1", Visibility.Visible },
                {"button2", Visibility.Hidden },
                {"button3", Visibility.Visible }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
       <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Кнопка 1" Visibility="{Binding Path=VisibilityDictionary[button1]}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=EnabledDictionary[button1]}" Tag="1" />
        <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="Кнопка 2" Visibility="{Binding Path=VisibilityDictionary[button2]}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=EnabledDictionary[button2]}" Tag="2" />
        <Button Grid.Column="3" Content="Кнопка 3" Visibility="{Binding Path=VisibilityDictionary[button3]}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=EnabledDictionary[button3]}" Tag="3" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Если хотите чтобы это все было в 1 словаре - пишите конвертер

Comment: Я тоже думал в сторону конвертёра, но как ему передать ключ? Multibinding, как https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799705/wpf-dictionary-binding-where-key-variable

Comment: @АртемийСоболев a что у вас является ключом?

Comment: Предполагалось все элементы пронумеровать в Tag и это значение использовать как ключ. @Alias ниже, предлагает использовать UId

Comment: @АртемийСоболев элементы управления из кода создаются? я чето не понимаю зачем такие сложности

Comment: Нет, элементы управления заранее созданы в разметке. Сложности только в том, что каждому UserControlу нужен свой набор кнопочек и прочих красивостей

Comment: @АртемийСоболев тогда чем вам не подходит мой вариант?

Comment: такой подход сработает только для однотипных словарей свойств, но при этом он содержит заранее наполненные в C# словари -- а в конструкторе формы можно было бы сделать гибче, например обработать словарь разнотипных свойств.

Comment: @AlexandrAlexandr Ваш вариант вполне подходит. Только вариант с одним словарем на все значения свойств. Вот и спрашивал про мультибиндинг, как в данном случае это реализовать (ранее не сталкивался с этим зверем). А про привязку к ключу - это зашоренность мышления. Уже вторую неделю пытаюсь разрешить этот вопрос

Comment: @Alias Для устранения однотипности значений словаря можно сделать класс, содержащий эти разные значения, и связанные только одним элементом управления. Значения свойств будут передаваться из UserControl в основную форму, и уже она должна прибиндить все свойства. Писать длинный обработчик для каждого элемента управления, здесь я для примера показал немного контролов, чревато ошибками. поэтому хотелось бы забиндить свойства на словарь